# Ruby metaprogramming with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, mongomapper

I'm trying to dynamically add keys to MongoMapper documents.

```
def build(attrs={})
  doc = self.new
  apply_scope(doc)
  doc.set_up_keys!
  doc.attributes = attrs
  doc
end

def set_up_keys!
  return unless form

  form.fields.each do |f|
    next if self.keys.include?(f.underscored_name)

    self.class.send(:key, f.underscored_name, f.keys['default'].type, :required => f.required, :default => f.default)
  end
end
```

The code in question is available [here](https://github.com/noodall/noodall-form-builder/blob/feature/rails-3.2-compatibility/app/models/noodall/form_response.rb#L52) and [here](https://github.com/noodall/noodall-form-builder/blob/feature/rails-3.2-compatibility/app/models/noodall/form.rb#L21).

`form` is a related model. I want to create keys on the current model (self) based on what `form#fields` has.

The problem is that if I create two models, they both have the same keys from both models.

`self.class.send(:key...)` adds the keys to the model.

Why are they being added to both models?

Is it because the method is being called in a class context?

How can I affect only the individual instance?

Comment: Don't send it to the class.

Comment: But isn't #key a class method? Not sure I follow :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongomapper defines a model by its class. All instances of this class share the model's keys. If you want to create a model on-the-fly, you will probably need to [dynamically create a class](http://johnragan.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/ruby-metaprogramming-dynamically-defining-classes-and-methods/), and add the keys to it:

```
def build(attrs={})
  c = Class.new(self.class)
  doc = c.new
  apply_scope(doc)
  doc.set_up_keys!
  doc.attributes = attrs
  doc
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change it slightly to `c = Class.new(klass.new.class)` but apart from that it works great. I changed the original code to use `#send` on `self.class` instead of `class_eval` because of a different problem. That's when this new problem arose. Does `class_eval` only affect the class of the instance (singleton class/eigenclass), not the class of all classes?

Comment: AFAIK `class_eval` is a class method, not an instance method, so the question seems moot - it affects the class it is called upon.